# Laravel library HeadlessChromium

Tags: php, laravel

i am using this code by using headlesschromium pakage of lereval (composer require chrome-php/chrome)

```
use HeadlessChromium\BrowserFactory;

 $options = [
                'headless' => true,
                'noSandbox' => true,
                'keepAlive' => true,
                'disable-gpu' => true,// add this flag to show the browser window
                'closeOnExit' => false, // set this option to false to keep the browser open
                'userDataDir' => '/tmp'

            ];
$browserFactory = new BrowserFactory('google-chrome-stable');
$browser = $browserFactory->createBrowser();
$page = $browser->createPage();
$page->navigate('https://www.google.com')->waitForNavigation();
```

this code gives me error---

Chrome process stopped before startup completed.

while i am using on live server

on local server it is working fine

Please let me know if anyone have any solution of this.

Comment: If you are using it on the live server then you need to make sure the user has the correct permissions

Comment: after giving all permissions still gives the error "Chrome process stopped before startup completed."  and we are not open the browser on server